# Matplotlib seemingly not compatible with PySide6 in Spyder

Tags: matplotlib, graph, spyder, pyside6

I am using Spyder for developing `Python` programs and currently I am struggling with incorporating an interactive graphics into the project. I have already tried `plotly` combined with `QWebEngineView` and it produces pleasant results. I gave up after an unsuccessful tremendous effort of making the outer `QScrollArea` still scrollable even if the mouse cursor is over the `plotly` graph. Now I am trying to incorporate a `matplotlib` graph. However, the `Spyder` environment resolutely prevents me get my project up and running!

The program is right now extremely big, but I give a minimal example depicting the exact same problem. The example is taken from [this website](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyside6-plotting-matplotlib/):

```
import sys
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create the maptlotlib FigureCanvas object,
        # which defines a single set of axes as self.axes.
        sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        sc.axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])
        self.setCentralWidget(sc)

        self.show()

app = QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

The error:

```
...
File c:\path\to\the\project.py:29 in __init__
    self.setCentralWidget(sc)

TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(MplCanvas)
Supported signatures:
  PySide6.QtWidgets.QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

I spent days consulting the literature and looking for the solution on the internet. Even the artificial intelligence 'noticed' this problem is already known and came to a conclusion that '`matplotlib` is unfortunately not yet compatible with `PySide6`'! I almost gave up one more time.

After I ran my project via `python .\project.py` from the command prompt, I realized my code (and the given example as well) works like a charm, without any single error.

My question: how can I make `matplotlib` be fully compatible with `PySide6` in `Spyder` environment?

Answer (score 0):

PySide6 and PyQT have the same origin, and you should only use one of them to avoid overlapping functions. The editor Spyder is a PyQT application, so it will automatically preload some packages from PyQT and cause errors when PySide6 is loaded. This has nothing to do with the Python environment though. You can use your code with Anaconda Python in any other editor. Don't use Spyder for this and it should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).